# How can I apply closest to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I want to be able to calculate Section 1, Section 2, and Section 3 **individually(separately)**.
in this source only Section 1 calculated, but Section 2 and Section 3 do not work.
How can I calculate Section 1, Section 2, and Section 3 individually?

### p.s : The number of sections may change.

```js
$(".btn-primary").on( "click", function(event) {
  var $final = parseFloat($("#final").val());
  var $first = parseFloat($("#first").val());

  $('#is_nums').text($final - $first);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  Section 1
  <h4>A : <input type="text" name="final" id="final" value="">
  <h4>B : <input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="calc">confirm</button>
  <b>calc</b> : <label id="is_nums"></label></h4>

  Section 2
  <h4>A : <input type="text" name="final" id="final" value="">
  <h4>B : <input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="calc">confirm</button>
  <b>calc</b> : <label id="is_nums"></label></h4>

  Section 3
  <h4>A : <input type="text" name="final" id="final" value="">
  <h4>B : <input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="calc">confirm</button>
  <b>calc</b> : <label id="is_nums"></label></h4>
```

Comment: `ID should be unique` use class instead then you can use `.prev()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about a good, nested structure of HTML.
If you organize your HTML-code this way, then JS will become clear and transparent, without using `.prev()` or other things which can stop working after minor HTML modifications.
You should not rely on order of elements, you should rely on its logical structure.

Class namings are according to [BEM](https://en.bem.info/), you can follow any other guidelines, it doesn't matter.

```js
$(".my-section__calc").on("click", function(event) {
  var $section = $(this).closest(".my-section");

  var final = parseFloat($section.find(".my-section__final").val());
  var first = parseFloat($section.find(".my-section__first").val());

  $section.find(".my-section__result").text(final - first);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-section">
  <h5>Section 1</h5>

  A: <input type="number" class="my-section__final" name="final" value="0"><br/>
  B: <input type="number" class="my-section__first" name="first" value="0"><br/>
  <button class="my-section__calc">confirm</button><br/>
  <b>calc</b>: <label class="my-section__result"></label>
</div>

<div class="my-section">
  <h5>Section 2</h5>

  A: <input type="number" class="my-section__final" name="final" value="0"><br/>
  B: <input type="number" class="my-section__first" name="first" value="0"><br/>
  <button class="my-section__calc">confirm</button><br/>
  <b>calc</b>: <label class="my-section__result"></label>
</div>

<div class="my-section">
  <h5>Section 3</h5>

  A: <input type="number" class="my-section__final" name="final" value="0"><br/>
  B: <input type="number" class="my-section__first" name="first" value="0"><br/>
  <button class="my-section__calc">confirm</button><br/>
  <b>calc</b>: <label class="my-section__result"></label>
</div>
```